# Tableau Online - only allow embedded report and prevent direct access

Tags: tableau-api

I am pretty new to Tableau. I have a couple of tableau reports embedded in my react web project, but I don't want users to have direct access to my Tableau Online server.

From my research, I found [Trusted Authentication](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm), but I don't fully understand it and not sure whether Trusted Authentication is what I need.

Does anyone have any similar experience? Will [Trusted Authentication](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm) prevent users from directly accessing my Tableau Online Server while still allowing embedding?

Comment: How are you currently embedding the reports?

Comment: @Talvalin, I am using tableau-react npm package for embedding